# Firebase real time database query sub child

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is how my DB look like:
[image: This is how my DB look like:]

I manage to get all the document by query the `userId`:

```
this.orderListRef = firebase.database().ref(`/orderList`);
this.orderListRef.orderByChild('userId').equalTo(`${this.currentUser.uid}`)
```

But i **having problem to get all the document by query the sub key** `restId` in the `order` array, i did try below codes but it just return `null`:

```
this.orderListRef.orderByChild('order/restId').equalTo('-L6vQHDBv9WugS_yTibn').on('value', snap => {
      console.log(snap.val())
    })
```

and

```
this.orderListRef.child('order').orderByChild('restId').equalTo('-L6vQHDBv9WugS_yTibn').on('value', snap => {
  console.log(snap.val())
})
```

Please help.. I would like to get return that contain `"-L6vQHDBv9WugS_yTibn"` in the `restId` key only, like:

```
-L9IZKHkueFppGMJY3Z9: {deliveryAddress: "Kuala Lumpur, Federal Territory of Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia", dtcreate: 1522894198149, order: Array(2), userId: "AeMgnwHy3Hav3FE9DyTMJVdp4QX2", userOrderNumber: "pGMJY3Z9"}
-L9I_DcXgx_fjsmsn2rm: {deliveryAddress: "Kuala Lumpur, Federal Territory of Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia", dtcreate: 1522894433661, order: Array(2), userId: "AeMgnwHy3Hav3FE9DyTMJVdp4QX2", userOrderNumber: "jsmsn2rm"}
-L9IksHXG4WZo0ejfmk1: {deliveryAddress: "Kuala Lumpur, Federal Territory of Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia", dtcreate: 1522897487221, order: Array(2), userId: "AeMgnwHy3Hav3FE9DyTMJVdp4QX2", userOrderNumber: "o0ejfmk1"}
```

Thank you in advance!

**Edited 1:**
After Frank van Puffelen suggest the method of creating `restaurant` as a child of the orderList > ID, i found that it is good idea and i tried, but still no luck.

Heres the new screenshot of my DB:
[image]

I have tried with below queries but everyone still returning `null`:

```
this.orderListRef.orderByChild('restaurant').equalTo('rest001').once('value', snap => {
      console.log(snap.val())
    })

this.orderListRef.child('restaurant/rest001').once('value', snap => {
      console.log(snap.val())
    })
this.orderListRef.child('restaurant').equalTo('rest001').once('value', snap => {
      console.log(snap.val())
    })

this.orderListRef.child('restaurant').orderByChild('rest001').once('value', snap => {
      console.log(snap.val())
    })
```

Thank you for responding!

Answer (score 0):

There is no field `order/restId`. There *are* fields `order/0/restId` and `order/1/restId`, but since that isn't a fixed path you can't query on them.

Your current data structure is suited to finding the restaurant IDs for a given order. It is not well suited to finding the orders for a given restaurant ID. To allow that, you should expand your data structure to have the inverted data:

```
restaurants
  restaurantId1
    order1: true
    order3: true
  restaurantId2
    order2: true
```

Now you can find the orders for a given restaurant by simply looking them up under `/restaurants/$restaurantId`.

For more on this see:

- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)
- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)

Comment: unfortunately i still don get the result.. i did try following query: `this.orderListRef.orderByChild('restaurant').equalTo('rest001').once('value', snap => {
      console.log(snap.val())
    })` , 

   ` this.orderListRef.child('restaurant/rest001').once('value', snap => {
      console.log(snap.val())
    })` , 
   ` this.orderListRef.child('restaurant').equalTo('rest001').once('value', snap => {
      console.log(snap.val())
    })`
 ,
    `this.orderListRef.child('restaurant').orderByChild('rest001').once('value', snap => {
      console.log(snap.val())
    })`

Comment: fyi, i added `restaurant` as a child of orderList. `orderList > Id > restaurant` . then i added `rest001` and `rest002` as the child of `restaurant`, and `{order1:true}` as child of `rest001` and `rest002`

Comment: Please update your question with the new information. As you might notice, longer code in comments is almost impossible to read.

Comment: I have updated the question, please have a check. Thanks for responding!

Comment: None of those queries will indeed work, since you're constantly calling `child()` or `orderByChild()` on a path that doesn't exist in the context where you call it. I recommend adding an inverted data structure, which is explained in my answers to both questions I linked.